# Não consigo inserir um linear gradient na cor preta

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando fazer o efeito linear gradient para deixar a parte de baixo da imagem com "degradê" preto, mas quando eu coloco o comando, independente da cor que eu uso, ele fica branco, segue código para visualização:

```
        -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 1%, #000000 30%);
```

A imagem fica deste jeito:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria que a parte de baixo fosse preta, pra seguir o fluxo da seção logo abaixo a imagem, mas não importa a cor que eu insiro no código (no caso #000000), ela sempre fica branca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A propriedade `-webkit-mask-image` na verdade cria uma gradiente de opacidade como vc pode ver nessa questão [Com CSS é possível mesclar duas Imagens?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349808/com-css-%c3%a9-poss%c3%advel-mesclar-duas-imagens)

Então o branco que vc está vendo na verdade é a cor de fundo da página.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Uma das formas de corrigir isso é colocar a imagem dentro de uma `div` com o `background black` por exemplo.

```css
body {background: red;}

img {
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 1%, #000000 30%);
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200">

<div>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/200/200">
</div>
```

Comment: muitissimo obrigado hugo!!!!

Comment: @EduardoKusdraFilho cara se a resposta te ajudou e resolveu considere marcar ela como aceita nesse ícone ✔︎ logo abaixo das setinhas ao lado da  resposta :)

Comment: opa, coloquei aqui já! obrigado